# No data received ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to run webpack-dev-server, but when I go to `http://localhost:8080/` the browser returns

```
No data received 
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

**Solution**

I was able to resolve this issue by explicitly telling webpack to use port 3000

```
webpack-dev-server --port 3000
```

run on `http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: Same issue but I dont understand why it work with port 3000.

Comment: It actually works with any [Registered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Registered_ports)  ports number. We just need to explicitly tell it the port number O.o

Comment: we had this problem (on a mac) also, for some reason specifying port 3000 from commandline caused it to work, specifying 8080 from commandline wont work.

Comment: If not working with any other specified port (registered or not), should be considered as a bug/issue. A workaround has been documented under their github's issues: https://github.com/tylermcginnis/react-fundamentals/issues/8

Answer (score 0):

This was happening on my laptop, and when I switched ports, it started working again.

I found there was a hung process still using the old port, but webpack/express didn't complain when it started up.

`ps -ef | grep npm`